# Block fill in date puzzle

Tags: polyomino, packing

[image]

I have been trying this puzzle for HOURS!!! The goal is the fit all the pieces but not cover Aug or 1. You can rotate the pieces.

Credit to [www.dragonfjord.com](http://www.dragonfjord.com)
The link shown at the bottom of the picture,
https://www.dragonfjord.com/product/a-puzzle-a-day/
shows a physical version of the puzzle which you can buy.

Comment: In order that both '1' and 'Aug' are not covered, the orange 'L' must be in the top left, covering Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, and Jun.

Comment: That should be 'and Jul' (and now it appears to be past the 'edit' window for my comment)

Comment: @enkorvaks the gray U shaped piece at the bottom could also go in the top left corner

Comment: @ferret I know (now) - I spent about 10 minutes and got another solution with the U piece in the top left (the first solution had the L there).

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 (L in the top left):

> L in the top left, Z in the top right.The U shape is directly below the Z (right hand side) covering 13, 14, 21, 27 and 28. The purple elongated S is at the bottom left. The yellow-green L is towards the top right, next to the Z, covering Sep, Oct, Nov, 5, and 12. The blue rectangle covers 2, 3, 4, 9, 10 and 11. The dark pink T covers 17, 18, 19, 20, and 26. The pink notched-rectangle covers the remaining numbers other than 1.

Solution 2 (U in the top left):

> U in the top left, Z in the top right. Yellow-green L between them covering Apr, Oct, 2, 3, and 4. Orange L below that, covering 8, 9, 10, 11, and 15. Rectangle covering 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, and 31. Elongated S covering 16, 17, 18, 25, and 26. Notched rectangle covering 14, 20, 21, 27, and 28. Dark pink T covers Nov, 5, 12, 13, and 19.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

Comment: @bobble I can't see an 'off-topic' notice on this question, or else I would not have answered it. I am happy to delete the answer, if that is a reasonable response to this comment.

Comment: It would be reasonable to delete the answer until such time as the OP updates their question with proper attribution. No worries about making a mistake; take some time to review the policy I linked so you know what questions are on- or off- topic

Comment: @bobble OK, thanks for letting me know. I don't answer where the post is actually flagged as off-topic, but this one hadn't been so far. I will delete the answer shortly after posting this comment.

Comment: The off-topic banner doesn't show up until the question is actually closed, which takes five votes. This means that questions which clearly violate policy are left "open" for some time while they accumulate votes. Thus it makes it the responsibility of potential answerers to determine whether a question violates policy or not before answering. In this case, the comment I posted asking for attribution would warn away people with more experience with the site; it's not your fault for not having such experience, which is why I'm happy to link you to the policy. Thank you for listening.

Comment: @bobble thank you for taking the time to both explain policy, and explain your actions. I appreciate that you understand I am relatively new to this particular SE sub-site and don't know all of the habits and expected behaviours. I will endeavour in future to be wary of answering such questions, and hold off posting an answer until there is attribution (or withhold answer if it's closed).